# How to split large txt file into small txt files by line using python

Tags: python, text, split

I have a large txt file contains 1 million lines, I want to split them into small txt files each contains 10 lines, how to do it using python?
I found some related questions and have code like this :

```
def split_file(filepath, lines=30):

    """Split a file based on a number of lines."""

    path, filename = os.path.split(filepath)

    # filename.split('.') would not work for filenames with more than one .

    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    # open input file

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f_in:

        try:
            # open the first output file
            f_out = open(os.path.join(path, '{}_{}{}'.format(basename, 0, ext)), 'w')
            # loop over all lines in the input file, and number them
            for i, line in enumerate(f_in):
                # every time the current line number can be divided by the
                # wanted number of lines, close the output file and open a
                # new one
                if i % lines == 0:
                    f_out.close()
                    f_out = open(os.path.join(path, '{}_{}{}'.format(basename, i, ext)), 'w')
                # write the line to the output file
                f_out.write(line)
        finally:
            # close the last output file
            f_out.close()
```

However it only functions in small txt file but does not work in my target file, and does not have error information I don't know why.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've updated thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this in python when command line utilities already exist to do the same thing?

Comment: it is too large, command line -split utilities don't work

Comment: @zjsuper So, which  command-line utilities did you try, what OS, and how did they fail?

Comment: Try command line utilities, if you are using Windows open cygwin and type - split -l 1000(no of lines you want to splits) filename.txt, this will make your work done in seconds

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It's a little roundabout, but should circumvent your mystery error while being human readable.

First let's define a couple of useful functions. The first reads a file and makes each line a list element, and the second writes lists as files.

Note, the second function will create a new file if no file with that name exists or overwrite the file if one does.

```
def line_reader(target_file):    
    with open(target_file, 'r') as file:
        store = file.readlines()
        return store

def line_writer(file_name, store):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(store)
```

Next, let's define the function that will actually break files into smaller files.

```
def breakdown(target, new_file_name, chunk_length = 10):
    # First let's store a list representing the data from the original file
    data = line_reader(target)

    # part_no is solely for naming purposes
    part_no = 0
    # this list will be used to hold smaller chunks of lines
    tmp_list = []
    condition = True
    while condition:
        for i in range(chunk_length):
            # just a basic check to make sure that there are still lines left to be replaced
            if len(data) > 0:
                tmp_list.append(data.pop(0))
            else:
                condition = False
                tmp_list.append('\n')
                break

        part_no += 1
        line_writer(str(new_file_name + ' ' + str(part_no)), tmp_list)
        tmp_list = []
```

Calling breakdown will split target into smaller files of `chunk_length` lines (10 by default) followed by a single blank line at the end. The last file will just be whatever's left from the original file.

Comment: Great solution. Works.